# Why is Alec trying to get a job in an Electronics Store?

Tags: continuum

Alec Saddler is a boy genius, in fact in the future he goes on to revolutionise technology with various inventions including 'liquid chip' technology, amongst other things, that he created both from his own knowledge and that left to him by his father.

He *knows* that he is clever and takes pleasure in reminding Kiera about it many times throughout the first season.

So, why is it that at the start of the second season he has decided to get a job at an electronics store? Even mediocre programmers can make better money than he'd earn from selling electronics to consumers so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Same way as i decided my occupation, on random basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We now know what the message from the future contained, a warning about the path he would walk down and how it pretty much destroyed the world.  In that light, no wonder he tried to distance himself from both Keira and all the advanced stuff - including advanced programming - and seek a job way under his abilities.  He may also have feared that getting a more suitable job to his talents - eg. as a programmer - was the first step he took... got job, advanced programming, got noticed, got power, ended up leading the company and taking humanity down the wrong path.  Besides, even if he is a good programmer, it's hardly easy for teenager to get a posh job without formal education and practice in the field; and he probably needed money as quickly as possible (rent and such).

Comment: but he's known from very early on in the first season that he created his own company - SadTech - using one of the logos he sketched in his book, surely if he was avoiding repeating the future he would simply avoid creating his own company and pursuing the liquid chip technology he had been handed down from his father?